# Expected string or bytes like object

Tags: python

I am following 1 Kaggle notebook to figure the personality but I always faced an error. kindly tell me how can I get my own personality type by following this. Here is the link of notebook.
https://www.kaggle.com/tgdivy/mbti-personality-classifier
and the piece of code in which I faced error(in the last line)

```
 def tellmemyMBTI(input, name, traasits=[]):
   a = []
   trait1 = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0],['I','N','T','J'],['count'])
   trait2 = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0],['E','S','F','P'],['count'])
   for i in input:
       a += [MBTI(i)]
   for i in a:
       for j in ['I','N','T','J']:
           if(j in i):
               trait1.loc[j]+=1                
       for j in ['E','S','F','P']:
           if(j in i):
               trait2.loc[j]+=1 
   trait1 = trait1.T
   trait1 = trait1*100/len(input)
   trait2 = trait2.T
   trait2 = trait2*100/len(input)
   
   
   #Finding the personality
   YourTrait = ''
   for i,j in zip(trait1,trait2):
       temp = max(trait1[i][0],trait2[j][0])
       if(trait1[i][0]==temp):
           YourTrait += i  
       if(trait2[j][0]==temp):
           YourTrait += j
   traasits +=[YourTrait] 
   labels = np.array(results.columns)

   intj = trait1.loc['count']
   ind = np.arange(4)
   width = 0.4
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
   rects1 = ax.bar(ind, intj, width, color='royalblue')

   esfp = trait2.loc['count']
   rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, esfp, width, color='seagreen')

   fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
   
   

   ax.set_xlabel('Finding the MBTI Trait', size = 18)
   ax.set_ylabel('Trait Percent (%)', size = 18)
   ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
   ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
   ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,105, step= 10))
   ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
   ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,105, step= 10))
   ax.set_title('Your Personality is '+YourTrait,size = 20)
   plt.grid(True)
   
   
   fig.savefig(name+'.png', dpi=200)
   
   plt.show()
   return(traasits),

My_writings = open('/content/my_posts.rtf')
my_writing = My_writings.readlines()
my_posts = my_writing[0].split('|||') 
len(my_posts)

trait=tellmemyMBTI(my_posts, 'Divy')


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-001295e03777> in <module>()
----> 1 print(tellmemyMBTI(mu_posts, 'Dibhvy'))

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)
  1287     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
  1288         last_break = 0
-> 1289         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
  1290             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
  1291             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Can you include the full error? Then we know on what line it went wrong.

Comment: I added the full error.

Comment: Your error doesn't exist in the snippet you gave us. And try not using reserved keywords such as `input` to name variables. And this `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)` part is where you should be looking.